# ¿URL amigables para diferentes páginas en un mismo sitio?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo

Quiero que todas las páginas redireccionen adecuadamente, la web tiene diferentes niveles de carpetas y paginas de categorías y detalle de producto o servicio, anexo código como lo tengo en el .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

#Pagina de servicio en carpeta raíz, redirecciona bien!!
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ experiencia.php?xs=$1&sv=$2 [NC,L]

#Página de detalle servicio en directorio raíz, redirecciona bien!!
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ servicio.php?srv=$1 [NC,L]


#Página en carpeta /tienda-de-regalos/ (categorías productos),redirecciona mal, lo hace a la página experiencia en el directorio raíz
RewriteRule ^tienda-de-regalos/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ tienda-de-regalos/category.php?ttp=$1  [QSA,L]

#También debo adicionar re dirección a pagina de detalle productos, página en carpeta /tienda-de-regalos/
RewriteRule ^tienda-de-regalos/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ tienda-de-regalos/product.php?ttp=$1  [QSA,L]
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a cambiar el orden en el que ejecutas las reglas? Piensa que `L` significa "last rule", por lo que si el patrón encaja con la página raíz no lo hará con las siguientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un problema con el [indicador `L` de `RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> **'last|L' (last rule)**
>
> Stop the rewriting process here and don't apply
>   any more rewrite rules. This corresponds to the Perl `last` command or
>   the `break` command in C. Use this flag to prevent the currently
>   rewritten URL from being rewritten further by following rules. For
>   example, use it to rewrite the root-path URL (`/`) to a real one,
>   e.g., `/e/www/`.

En castellano:

> **'last|L' (última regla)**
>
> Detiene el proceso de reescritura aquí y no aplica más reglas.
>   Corresponde al comando Perl `last` o `break` de C. Use este indicador
>   para evitar que la regla actual sea reescrita por las siguientes reglas.
>   Por ejemplo, úselo para reescribir la ruta raíz (`/`) a una real, 
>   por ejemplo `/e/www/`.

De modo que las URLs que te fallan están siendo tratadas por las primeras dos reglas y no llegan a ser analizadas por las últimas dos.

Si no quieres que otras reglas modifiquen las dos últimas, deberías ponerlas las primeras (en orden de preferencia):

```
#Página en carpeta /tienda-de-regalos/ (categorías productos),redirecciona mal, lo hace a la página experiencia en el directorio raíz
RewriteRule ^tienda-de-regalos/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ tienda-de-regalos/category.php?ttp=$1  [QSA,L]

#También debo adicionar re dirección a pagina de detalle productos, página en carpeta /tienda-de-regalos/
RewriteRule ^tienda-de-regalos/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ tienda-de-regalos/product.php?ttp=$1  [QSA,L]

#Pagina de servicio en carpeta raíz, redirecciona bien!!
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ experiencia.php?xs=$1&sv=$2 [NC,L]

#Página de detalle servicio en directorio raíz, redirecciona bien!!
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ servicio.php?srv=$1 [NC,L]
```

NOTA: Fíjate que las dos últimas reglas (ahora las primeras) son EXACTAMENTE iguales, por lo que sólo se ejecutará de manera efectiva la primera, las segunda nunca se cumplirá. Deberías usar algún texto o patrón que las identifique de manera única.

Comment: Oscar eres la ley!, ya funcionan como deben las redirecciones, te agradezco tu ayuda, y exactamente en el producto ingrese una tercer variable para que no conflictuara con la de categorías.

Pasa bien, saludos!

Comment: Me alegra haber sido de ayuda :) ¡saludos!